# How to style each element of ngFor individually based on its value?

Tags: css, angular

I have a console on the screen that I log things to. The component looks like this.

```
export class AppComponent { logs: string[]; ... }

<div *ngFor="let log of logs" class="log-type-a">{{log}}</div>
```

I'd like to set a class on each of the DIVs dynamically. At the moment, each of those is *log-type-a* but I'd prefer it to be *log-type-b* when the string contains a certain value (e.g. it starts with "b", so that the class would be *log-type-**first_char_of_log***.

I'm not sure what to google for to being with. I've tried horsing around with [*ngClass*](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) but failed due to ignorance and uncertainty on how.

Answer (score 2):

NgFor can have an index, like this one: `*ngFor="let item of items; index as i;"`
You could use that index in order to set different classes for your items, like `class="log-type-{{ i }}"`.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize I wan't clear on the aim. The classes are **not** dependent on the index of the elements. It's rather that when a log element contains the text "error", I want it to be red and otherwise to be blue. But I might use the index to look into the element and pipe out the style maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expresion in ngClass like this:

```
export class AppComponent { logs: string[]; ... }

<div *ngFor="let log of logs" [ngClass]="'log-type-' + log">{{log}}</div>
```

If your logs array has lets say: red and blue 
the class output should be:

```
log-type-red
log-type-blue
```

**OR**

you can use functions like this and make decisions depending on the log value:

```
<div *ngFor="let log of logs" [ngClass]="'class-test-' + ngClassConvert (log)">
  My log value: {{ log }}
  Converted in cssClass: {{ ngClassConvert (log)}}
</div>
```

and the component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  logs: string[]; 

  ngClassConvert(value):string{
    let returnValue = '';
    switch (value){
        case 'a': { 
        returnValue = 'Apple';
        break; 
      } 
      case 'b': { 
        returnValue = 'Banana';
        break; 
      } 
      case 'c': { 
        returnValue = 'Cherry';
        break; 
      } 
      case 'd': { 
        returnValue = 'dddd';
        break; 
      } 
      default: { 
        returnValue = 'default';
        break; 
      } 
    }
    return returnValue;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.logs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  }
}
```

Also and [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2dyaot)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of SehaxX: You could parse the list of logs using a setter. This will save you function calls in the template.

```
private _logs: string[];
public parsedLogs: any[];

set logs(value: string[]) {
  this._logs = value;
  this.parsedLogs = this.parseLogs(value);
}

private parseLogs(logs: string[]): any[] {
  let parsed = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++){
    parsed.push({
      value: logs[i],
      style: this.ngClassConvert(logs[i])
    });
  }
  return parsed;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1h4b1x)